# Rails Routing can't read constraints when it has more than a word

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, ruby-on-rails-4

I have here a scope and constraints for the Rails routing

```
scope constraints: { category: /#{ CATEGORY_NAMES }/,
                     location: /#{ LOCATION_NAMES }/,
                    id:        /[0-9]+/ } do
  get ':category/:label-:location-:id', to: 'categories#show', as: :my_page  
end
```

the `:label` can be any parameterized string (e.g. need-something-here)

while the `:location` must be any matched from the `LOCATION_NAMES`

```
LOCATION_NAMES = "california|new-york|japan|china"
```

I have a problem for location with 2 words like New York / new-york

The routing keeps getting `new` as included on the `:label` constraint.

```
Parameters: {"category"=>"music", "title"=>"need-something-here-new", "location"=>"york", "id"=>"111"}
```

and only `york` is considered as the location...

I'm new to Rails and I'm not really that familiar with the routing yet. Hope you could help me.

I've tried... adding a `title: /.*(?=\.)/` to constraints but it's not working... the issue is still there.

Comment: In which file are these constants defined?

Comment: @zinovyev I've defined it from `config/initializers`

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your routes.rb is initialized prior to the initializer, where you have defined your constants in.

Try to manually require your own initializer with defined constants in the routes file.

```
require Rails.root.join('config', 'initializers', 'constants.rb')
```

The original quetion/answer was found here:
[Can routes.rb Access Initializers' code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18557403/can-routes-rb-access-initializers-code)

Comment: The constants from initializer file can be accessed within my routes file... I don't have issues when `location` has one word like `california`. The constraints for that can be read. I have issue when `location` consists of more than a word like `new-york`

Comment: Ah looks like I found out that my issue is on the regex

"new|new-york"

This is not exactly the data... I've defined the first word separately so it keeps getting that one initially.